# React: Setting the state of one variable inside another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I now there have been many questions on this topic, but I could not easily find a satisfying answer to my question. Consider the following example code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Clock() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = useState(0);

  const onClick = () => {
    setX((prevX) => {
      setY((prevY) => prevY + 1);
      return prevX + 1;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click to increase x and y</button>
      <div>x:{x}</div>
      <div>y:{y}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I run the React app in `StrictMode`, the first button press will set `x` and `y` to `1`. Subsequent button clicks increment `x` by `1` and `y` by `2`. I have the following questions about this:

1. I have understood that React double invokes state function in `StrictMode`. However, I do not see why this will only increment `y` by `2` and not `x`. And why does not occur on the first button click?
2. Of course, the code can be 'fixed' by not nesting the state calls. However, I wanted to know if nesting state calls should always be avoided, or if the should be written differently if one wants to write nested state calls.

Answer (score 0):

It only increments `y` by `2` and not `x` because `setY` update is still using the old state value from the previous update, and it is why y increments by 1 on the second click. It does not working on first click because it triggers both state updates to be scheduled and they get executed on the second click, nesting should be always avoided because they can lead to a lot of unexpected errors and bugs.